# How to display user profile with Ajax and Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I want to display a user profile picture(image) after he has submitted a review(instantly), I have set the relationship correctly and it was working perfect when I was using Laravel but now I want to use Ajax to display it live from database. So how can I display the profile picture instantly after a user has submitted a review?

Controller

```
  public function userRatingavatar($id){
    {
        $products = Product::where('id','=',$id)->with('reviews.user')->get();
        foreach ($products as $product)
        {
            foreach ($product->reviews as $review){
                echo  $review->user->avatar; //The data here is 1577015097(the image)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Route

```
 Route::get('userRatingavatar/{id}', 'ProductReviewController@userRatingavatar')->name('userRating.avatar');
```

Ajax

```
<script >
function userRatingavatar() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '{{route('
        userRating.avatar ', $id)}}',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#userRatingavatar').html('<img src="/uploads/avatars/'+data+'style="" alt="">');
            setTimeout(userRatingavatar, 1000);
        }
    });

  }
userRatingavatar();
</script>
```

Html

```
<span id="userRatingavatar"></span>
```

Answer (score -2):

maybe that's why

Add Ajax

```
async: false
```